# How to measure an 15 kV electric fence to 0-5 v analog input of a arduino?

Tags: arduino, voltage-divider

Good day

I am a mechanical engineering student who is dabbling in electronics right now and am having a little bit of trouble in one project

**The Project:** Making a gsm enabled voltage meter for monitoring electric fences.
**The Problem:** How do I convert 15 kV signal to 5 v that the arduino can read.
I have tried to make a voltage divider with a 10 M ohm and three 10k ohm resistors, but I found that it causes a minor shortage to ground when I wired it up. (I have a 0.3J 12v fence energizer which i use for testing and it went from 6.1 kV to 4.2 kV)
[image: Voltage divder circuit]
Extra: 
I have a meter that I does not require a physical ground connection that looks like this: 
[image: Digital Power Probe]
I have identified most of the components execopt L3(top left) which is some sort of coil and the spring(bottom left) which i am not sure if is for pcb stabalization or a psuedo ground connection.

The Questions

1. What component is L3 in the picture above?(says on top **102k 06039**)
2. The spring in the lower left corner of the picture of the pcb could it be used as a grounding mechanism of some sort. It touches some aluminium tape in the plastic enclosure and has no way to connect to ground?
3. What components are my best bet to use in this project for stepping down the voltage from 15kV to 5 V without draining the source? A transformer perhaps or are there any other circuits I could use, preferably without connecting to the ground wire of the fence but that's a preference not requirement.

Comment: ... 1.5mA is a *lot* of current to take from something that is supposed to *avoid* killing animals...

Comment: L3 is a 1mH inductor

Comment: Sorry about that. That is not necessarily the correct current i will take it out.

Comment: Irrelevant. You can only pull a few hundred microamps at most, and you're clearly pulling more.

Comment: 15kV will quite happily jump the air-gap across a 'normal' resistor. You'd be much better off splitting that 10M into 10 x 1M resistors.

Comment: I am using high voltage resistors

Comment: You can buy 100 Meg .025% 20KV resistors from Caddock through suppliers like Digi-Key, Mouser, etc. Use a CMOS op-amp per @tcrosley suggestion to bring it into the scale you need. Benefits include trimming for accuracy, and essentially no load to the HV line.

Comment: I think you will need a ground. I also think a transformer might work better for your input (rather than a voltage divider). The waveform is kind of a pulse, so the parasitic capacitance of your divider will form an RC low-pass filter with the resistors. Since the resistors are fairly large, the time constant might be fairly large, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be better of using two 100 Meg resistors in series, which will produce only 0.25V instead of 5V, but you can then run that through an op-amp with a 20x gain.  You'd be drawing just 75 µA instead of 1.5 mA.

I originally suggested using a remote controlled (via GSM) relay to open the circuit when not in use, so there's normally no load at all.  But in retrospect that's not a good idea since with no load, 15kV will appear at the NO terminal of the relay, not a good idea.

Comment: And if you're willing to look past the limited selection of MCUs that Arduino uses you can even find ones that can do the 20x gain internally, saving the extra components.

Comment: Two resistors is not enough since they will not take 7.5 kV each. Split it over 10 or 20 resistors and check their voltage rating.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post, but since I stumbled on it I might as well answer it for the next fellow.

1. I'm guessing the picture is from an advanced fence tester which also shows the current flowing through the wire. L3 is an inductor used to measures the magnetic field and correspondingly calculate the amount of current that is flowing through it. It is placed so as to stand very close and perpendicular to the fence wire. The fence voltage pulse also carries a current pulse.
2. Voltage is always measured between 2 points. Much like a mains AC testing screwdriver, the spring uses YOUR BODY to make a connection to earth. With a high enough sense resistor impedance, the current flowing through your body will be so small you aren't going to feel it. The colors on the big R1 TH resistor looks like a 4681, which would mean a 4600M ohm 1% resistor. Or it is (more probabbly) a 186G which would mean 18M ohm 5% resistor. Its big size is probably to avoid a spark between the air gap of its terminals. Putting my naked finger on the earth terminal produces a neglegible reading difference of 0 to +0.2kV compared to just holding the plastic case.
3. Even with an 8bit ADC at 5V you'll get about 0.02V resolution. For that to represent a 100V resolution you would only need to divide 15kV small enough to get 3V. Fense Testers are also no all that accurate. I have 2 different make fence testers and they show different values for different make fence energizers.
   The tester I mainly use has 3x 7.5Mohm big TH 1% resistors to a junction, then 2x 680kohm 1% 1206 resistors and finally a 2.2kohm 1% 0603 resistor, at which voltage seems to be sampled. The junction also has 2 further branches, AC coupled with a cap and then further divided with 2x 1.5Mohm each and some other circuit hidden under the display. I'm guessing it is for auto-wake-up as soon as a fence pulse is present.
   If you planed to use a transformer, you have to consider the high isolation required both within the primary winding (and/or winding distribution) and between the primary and secondary winding.
   Lower impedance means you'll be increasing the load on the fance and thus lowering its voltage, which is a downside if you plan on having a permanently connected circuit.